# Can i develop a .net project without visual studio ,if yes is .net framework is cost or freeware

Tags: java, .net

Everybody saying that java is freeware and .net is not freeware but i download and install .net framework to my lap and i can write asp.net code in freeware ide .can i able to  develop it without visual studio  and i want ti know which is not freeware .net or visualstudio

Comment: Hello. Your question does not seem to fit the established criteria on StackOverflow. We expect programming questions usually with some source code that can reproduce the problem. Please see what is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Also, checkout the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) website, where you can ask your question in place. Thank you.

Comment: "Everybody saying" - I don't know who you hang around with, but they're a bunch of liars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can develop without Visual Sturio. You could use `csc` or `msbuild` at the command line, you could use any of a *range* of alternative IDEs, or you could use [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx), which is **free**.

The .NET framework is freely available to Windows users.

Alternatively if "free" and "free" isn't good enough: Mono is also free, as is MonoDevelop.